# mongo java driver 3.4.3 replica set connection can't monitor members

Tags: java, mongodb, dns

Using : Ubuntu 16.04.3

I'm connecting to a replica set through mongodb java driver v3.4.3 (or 3.5.0) . I may create the MongoClient by providing the IPs , or the hostnames I have provided in the /etc/hosts file as such :

```
 new MongoClient( 
    Arrays.asList(
        new ServerAddress("X.X.Y.A",27017),
        new ServerAddress("X.X.Y.B",27017),
        new ServerAddress("X.X.Y.C",27017))
);
```

or

```
new MongoClient(new MongoClientURI("mongodb://X.X.Y.A:27017/?replicaSet=my-rs"));
```

or

```
//myserver1 on /etc/hosts  as X.X.Y.A    myserver1
new MongoClient(new MongoClientURI("mongodb://myserver1:27017/?replicaSet=my-rs"));
```

in both cases , mongodb is trying to monitor the replica sets as "mongodb1" , "mongodb2" and "mongodb3" and keeps throwing the INFO Log and prevents the execution :

```
Oct 18, 2017 9:12:13 AM com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger log
INFO: Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server mongodb3:27017
com.mongodb.MongoSocketException: mongodb1
    at com.mongodb.ServerAddress.getSocketAddress(ServerAddress.java:188)
    at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStreamHelper.initialize(SocketStreamHelper.java:57)
    at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:58)
    at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:115)
    at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:113)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: mongodb1
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1280)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1192)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1126)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getByName(InetAddress.java:1076)
    at com.mongodb.ServerAddress.getSocketAddress(ServerAddress.java:186)
    ... 5 more
```

Throwing the similar exceptions for "mongodb2" and "mongodb3" .

But when i add the mongodb1 etc rows on /etc/hosts file , everything works as :

```
X.X.Y.A   mongodb1
X.X.Y.B   mongodb2
X.X.Y.C   mongodb3
```

This leads me to think that mongo driver is hardcodedly monitoring the N members of the replicaset as "mongodbN:port". Is this a bug on mongodb java driver or just incredibly useless way of doing it ?

Comment: All drivers actually read the replica set members from the replica set itself. All you are supplying on connection is a "seed list" which are basically points to try when establishing a connection. Once the connection is made then the actual replica set configuration is used instead. There surely is an FAQ on this somewhere.

Comment: Thank you for reading the manual. So what's your comment on the actual problem i have mentioned ?

Comment: Well I kind of presumed that you clearly are not aware that is the case otherwise you would have ensured that both the servers and the clients were able to address the same fully qualified domain names. You are asking "why does it not use the IP address I provide?" and you just got answered why. So fix your configuration.

Comment: Okay so somewhat disappointing that the only real documented source I can find is from the [NodeJS driver documentation](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/reference/connecting/connection-settings/#ensure-your-connection-string-is-valid-for-replica-sets), but rest assured all drivers require the same considerations. *"You must ensure server1, server2 and server3 are resolvable from the **driver** for the Replicaset discovery and failover to work correctly."*. Which in short means the names used in `rs.config()` also need to be accessible from the client. Not a bug but intentional

Comment: @NeilLunn all members of the replica are resolvable through my /etc/host settings such as "myserver1" ,"myserver2" etc. And what about the usage where i give the IPs , not hostnames , in the MongoClient() builder ? This driver hardcodedly wants them to be resolvable as "mongodb1" , "mongodb2" etc .

Comment: Sorry went AFK for a bit. Sign into your replica set with a `mongo` shell and type in `rs.config()`. There is nothing "hardcoded in the driver", but instead the driver is using the values as they are present and shown in the `rs.config()` results. Each comment I have made is addressing your misconception that the "seed list" addresses are used for the connections. They are not, and are merely a means to contact "a" server, from which point the configuration the "server" has ( which is "mongodb1" etc ) is what gets used. You "client" needs to be aware of these hostnames to resolve.

Comment: Thank you so much. You are pinpoint right on my confusion. This is the answer. Can you post this as an answer please ?

Comment: The only reason I have not as yet is because I can't believe there is not a source for this. Which is why it took me so long to find "any" documentation source that actually referenced what happens. So I was basically still searching for a documented source.

Comment: @NeilLunn FYI, this behaviour is described in the [Server Discovery and Monitoring (SDAM)](https://github.com/mongodb/specifications/blob/master/source/server-discovery-and-monitoring/server-discovery-and-monitoring.rst#clients-use-the-hostnames-listed-in-the-replica-set-config-not-the-seed-list) spec implemented by the officially supported MongoDB drivers.